# Slow loading of node add/edit pages because of creating 65 fields in a content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have to create 65 fields in one content type which includes some field collections(with Add more option).

When I tried to create a node edit/add pages for that content type the page load is very slow and sometimes it is giving maximum memory exhausted error.

I am trying to see if this Multistep nodeform(https://www.drupal.org/project/msnf) will help me in faster page load or not. Also looking for other options like dividing these 65 fields to different content types and embed them as a entityreference in one content type etc..

Can anyone suggest any other best approaches to avoid slow page loads and avoiding any memory/timeout issues?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that you really need all 65 fields. I can't imagine entity that needs that many fields to be described. Also, instead of field collections can you use simple node reference field (drop-down, auto-select or some similar widget)?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't limit your filed counts (i.e. reference other entities with some fields instead of field collections). Otherwise, try conditionally increasing your PHP memory in settings.php:

```
if (isset($_GET['q']) && !empty($_GET['q'])) {
  $q = $_GET['q'];
  $pattern = '@^((node/\d+/edit)|(node/add/[\w_\-]+))@i';

  if (preg_match($pattern, $q)) {
    ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
  }
}
```

Change "512M" to increase or decrease based on memory needs.